# Can I revert StringDocument <Type> back into a string ? (TextAnalysis.jl)

Tags: nlp, julia

I'm making a spam classifier using a Naive Bayes Classifier model from the Julia [TextAnalysis.jl](https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/latest/classify/) package.

The text pre-processing [functions](https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/latest/documents/#Preprocessing-Documents-1) (like `remove_corrupt_utf8!(sd)` where `sd` is a `StringDocument`) can only be applied to Document types (specific to the package) and not to `string` type.

Is there any way I can convert this `StringDocument` back into a string to put back into my `dataframe`.

Current code:

```
#global messageLis = []
for row in eachrow(data)
    message = row.v2
    #push!(messageLis, message)
    StringDoc = StringDocument(message)
    remove_corrupt_utf8!(StringDoc) #to remove the corrupt characters (if any) in the message so that model doesnt fail
    #convert StringDoc back into a string so that text is preprocessed from the dataframe itself.
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`text`](https://juliatext.github.io/TextAnalysis.jl/latest/APIReference/#TextAnalysis.text-Tuple%7BFileDocument%7D) to access the processed string:

```
julia> str = StringDocument("here are some punctuations !!!...");

julia> prepare!(str, strip_punctuation)

julia> text(str)
"here are some punctuations "
```